# session is not storing value for the first time

Tags: php, ajax, excel, laravel

I am unable to print data in the **first run** but can get it to print in the **second run**.I want to print data in first run itself.

i have 3 files
1. main files sends ajax post,print data(main.php)
2. put sent data into session(put.php)
3. print data into excel(print.php)

**main.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo '<p class="first">ABC</p>'; //DOM IS <p class="first">ABC</p>
?>
$(document).ready(function(){
   var value = $('.first').text();
     myfun();
    function myfun(){
        $.post("put.php", {"content":value},function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
  }
  window.location.href ='print.php';
 });
```

**put.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["content"] = $_POST["content"];

?>
```

**print.php**
// these file print into excel code is simple

```
<?php 
session_start();
header("content-type:application/xls");
$table = '<table><tr><th>Name</th></tr>';
$table .='<tr><td>'.$_SESSION["content"].'</td></tr></table>';
echo $table;
header("content-Disposition: attachment; filename = new.xls");
?>
```

please help me,thanks in advance.

Comment: **1.** main.php can't possibly work? You do a `window.location.href ='print.php'` in the "onload"-callback, which means that as soon as the page is loaded, you redirect the page to `print.php`. **2.** You should double check your HTML in `print.php`. You are missing some `<tr></tr>` in your table definitions. You probably don't mean to have multiple tables either...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson,yes i have put <tr></tr> but same thing is happening,i want to call print.php at end is there any possibility?

Comment: You should really read up on javascript, ajax, asyncronomous functions, html, php and how the browser behaves... there seem to be many misunderstandings here.

Answer (score 1):

## Why

js won't stop exec when ajax not complete,
so you should redirect after ajax complete to make sure `$_SESSION["content"]` has set

## Fix

**change**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var value = $('.first').text();
     myfun(); //i was missing then 
    function myfun(){
        $.post("put.php", {"content":value},function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
  }
  window.location.href ='print.php';
 });
```

**to**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var value = $('.first').text();
     myfun(); //i was missing then
    function myfun(){
        $.post("put.php", {"content":value},function(data){
            console.log(data);
            window.location.href ='print.php';
        });
  }
 });
```

Comment: if whole operation is completed then only i want to print data.